# How to determine when solution lies within specified range

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to determine whether a solution to a recursion equation lies within a specified range. I have the following:

```
Solve[p0 == (p0 + m*p0 (1 - p0))*(1 - e), p0]

(*  {{p0 -> 0}, {p0 -> (e - m + e m)/((-1 + e) m)}} *)
```

I would like to know when the non-zero solution lies between 0 and 1, can someone  help me?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're solving over the `Reals`:

```
Solve[pO == (pO + mpO (1 - pO)) (1 - e) && 0 < pO < 1, pO, Reals]
(*
{{pO -> ConditionalExpression[(mpO - e mpO)/(e + mpO - e mpO),
    (0 < e < 1 && mpO > 0) || (e > 1 && mpO < 0) || (e < 0 && mpO < 0)]}}
*)
```

The condition in the `ConditionalExpression` is what you're looking for, I think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all variables are real, I would recommend using `Reduce` with an appropriate  option:

```
Reduce[pO == (pO + m pO (1 - pO)) (1 - e) && 0 < pO < 1, 
       {pO, e, m}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> ```
> (0 < pO < 1 && e < 1 && m == e/((-1 + e) (-1 + pO))) || 
> (0 < pO < 1 && e > 1 && m == e/((-1 + e) (-1 + pO)))
> ```

Appropriate ordering of variables may be advantageous  (the question might be more precise), so another approach:

```
Reduce[ pO == (pO + m pO (1 - pO)) (1 - e) && 0 < pO < 1, {e, m, pO}, Reals, 
              Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> ```
>    (e < 0 && m < -(e/(-1 + e)) && pO == (e - m + e m)/((-1 + e) m)) || 
>    (e == 0 && m == 0 && 0 < pO < 1) ||
>    (0 < e < 1 && m > -(e/(-1 + e)) && pO == (e - m + e m)/((-1 + e) m)) || 
>    (e > 1 && m < -(e/(-1 + e)) && pO == (e - m + e m)/((-1 + e) m))
> ```